# After uploading a file, how can I still use AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

In my application, I have an import data feature. Currently when someone uploads the CSV file and submits the page, they see the spinner indicating that the file is uploading. After about a minute or so, the page will refresh once the import is complete.

I wanted to make the page a little bit friendlier by adding a progress bar of the import. My import class loops over every line in the CSV to import the data, so I added a bit of code so that after every few loops, it will write the percentage to a file with the intent that I can use an AJAX request to read that file and display the percentage.

I came to the point where I wanted to read the file, but any AJAX request I send after submitting the form doesn't ever return back to me. It seems that the server knows that the page is going to be refreshed so it doesn't even bother. Looking at the requests in the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools shows the Status of (pending), and none of them ever change.

Is there some way that I can keep making AJAX requests after I submit a form? As a side note, the application needs to support IE9+ so using the File API to submit the file through AJAX is not an option.

Comment: Not that this is the case, but I have had my web host block my requests for a short time after calling multiple AJAX requests to quickly.

Comment: Upload the file in an iframe.

Comment: @gilly3, the iframe strips any form elements, and doesn't allow creation of form elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sessions this is what happens : The first request blocks the temporary session file for reading. The subsequent requests must wait for the lock to be released before the server can start to execute them.

This means also that you cannot use sessions for your progress display.

Also keep in mind that an important part of the wait time is due to the upload of the file. Depending on your treatment the upload time is probably much more important than the time for treatment. Therefore your progress bar will not give the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your page is called `importdata.php` and you are doing something like this in the script on that page to start monitoring progress:

```
importForm.onsubmit = monitorProgress;
```

What you can do is **host that entire page within an iframe**.  Create a new page to host the iframe.  If you want to keep your URL the same, rename the original page to `importdata_form.php` and call the new page `importdata.php`.  In the new page, include a script block and an iframe that fills the page.  Move the `<title>` from the original page to the new page.  Set the iframe's src to `importdata_form.php`.  Move the `monitorProgress` function to the script block in the new page.  Then change the `onsubmit` handler in the original page to reference the function in the parent window (see [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.parent)):

```
importForm.onsubmit = parent.monitorProgress;
```

Your new page might look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><!-- move title from original page to here --></title>
        <style>
            iframe {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                border: 0 none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function monitorProgress() {
                // your ajax calls here
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="importdata_form.php"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```